# Wagtail/Weasyprint URLFetchingError at /resume/generate

Tags: python, django, heroku, wagtail, weasyprint

I am doing my first django/wagtail project, where I use [this](https://github.com/adinhodovic/wagtail-resume) template to produce a resume. I've managed to publish my project via heroku and I'm able to load it. However I don't know how to tackle the error `URLFetchingError at /resume/generate` when I want to press "Get PDF".

Below you can see my full traceback and how I've set up my `urls.py` file. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin

from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.core import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.documents import urls as wagtaildocs_urls

from search import views as search_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('django-admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    path('documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    path('search/', search_views.search, name='search'),

]


if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    # Serve static and media files from development server
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + [
    # For anything not caught by a more specific rule above, hand over to
    # Wagtail's page serving mechanism. This should be the last pattern in
    # the list:
    path("", include(wagtail_urls)),

    # Alternatively, if you want Wagtail pages to be served from a subpath
    # of your site, rather than the site root:
    #    path("pages/", include(wagtail_urls)),

    # Wagtail-resume
    path("resume/", include("wagtail_resume.urls")),
    #path("generate/", include("wagtail_resume.urls")),
]
```

**Traceback**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://mighty-ridge-73883.herokuapp.com/resume/generate?page_id=4

Django Version: 3.2.5
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['home',
 'search',
 'wagtail.contrib.forms',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
 'wagtail.embeds',
 'wagtail.sites',
 'wagtail.users',
 'wagtail.snippets',
 'wagtail.documents',
 'wagtail.images',
 'wagtail.search',
 'wagtail.admin',
 'wagtail.core',
 'modelcluster',
 'taggit',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'wagtailmetadata',
 'wagtailmarkdown',
 'wagtail_resume',
 'storages']
Installed Middleware:
['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/weasyprint/urls.py", line 252, in fetch
    result = url_fetcher(url)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/weasyprint/urls.py", line 217, in default_url_fetcher
    response = urlopen(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

During handling of the above exception (HTTP Error 400: Bad Request), another exception occurred:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail_resume/views.py", line 42, in resume_pdf
    HTML(url=resume_url).write_pdf(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/weasyprint/__init__.py", line 222, in write_pdf
    self.render(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/weasyprint/__init__.py", line 172, in render
    return Document._render(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/weasyprint/document.py", line 396, in _render
    context = cls._build_layout_context(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/weasyprint/document.py", line 370, in _build_layout_context
    css = CSS(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/weasyprint/__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    with result as (source_type, source, base_url, protocol_encoding):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/weasyprint/__init__.py", line 430, in _select_source
    with result as result:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/weasyprint/__init__.py", line 440, in _select_source
    with fetch(url_fetcher, url) as result:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/weasyprint/urls.py", line 254, in fetch
    raise URLFetchingError('%s: %s' % (type(exc).__name__, str(exc)))

Exception Type: URLFetchingError at /resume/generate
Exception Value: HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request?
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says, `path("", include(wagtail_urls)),` should be the last pattern in the list, as it catches everything not matched by a more specific rule - your

```
path("resume/", include("wagtail_resume.urls")),
```

line will never be reached. You should move that above the wagtail_urls line.

Comment: Hi, Moving that line above the wagtail_urls line does not make any difference (according to the error message).

Comment: Looks like wagtail_resume is failing to get a usable URL for the page it's creating a PDF from - most likely because the site record in Settings -> Sites is configured wrongly.

Comment: By accident I managed to find out what caused the problem. My page was in both live + preview mode. By publishing it again so it was only in live mode it worked. Thank you for your effort :)